# Facebook Ads Purchase Tracking is not working with React Native FBSDK Next

Tags: android, react-native, facebook, facebook-ads

I have developed a mobile app on react native. FBSDK Next is implemented as well and followed all the steps. Our app has in-app purchases for the monthly subscription which we want to track and to be shown in purchases in Facebook Ads Reporting.

In Facebook guidelines for FBSDK App Events, it is told that the fb_mobile_purchase event will be tracked automatically but it is not happening when I do purchases and check it in Event Debugger.

When I tried to add this event manually, it is working but it is not working automatically as described in Facebook Documentation.
[image]

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-android

How to resolve this issue and make it automatically logged.

- react-native : 0.66.1
- react-native-fbsdk-next : ^4.6.0
- facebook-android-sdk : 12.0.0